# Keeping instances of a class between methods

Tags: objective-c, object, nsmutablearray

I have a class `Payroll` and I am trying to store instances of another class, `Employee`, in a `NMutableArray` which I initalize in like so:

`array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];`

My `Employee` class contains `NSMutableStrings`variables which hold information about each employee.

My `Payroll` class has two methods that I am using. The first method gets the instances of the employee class and then put them in my `NSMutableArray` and that works fine.

The problem I have is that when I access the objects that I put in the array in my first method while in my second method the `NSMutableStrings` I get out are a bunch of random numbers which is no where close to what I expected.

My NSMutableArray is declared like this in my `Payroll.h` file:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray* array;
```

My first method just contains a while loop that looks like this:

```
while(next == true)
{
    Employee* emp = [[[Employee alloc] init] retain];

    //set values of Employee class

   [array addObject:emp];

}
```

My second method looks like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < [array count]; i++)
{
   Empoyee* emp = [array objectAtIndex: i];

   NSLog(emp->name);
}
```

`Payroll.h` looks like this:

```
@interface Payroll
{

   bool next; 
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray* array;

-void(getEmployee);
-void(doStuff);

@end
```

`Employee.h`looks something like this:

```
@interface Employee : NSObject
{
    NSMutableString* name;

}
@end
```

I am new to objective-c so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Why you are using `->` deference operator. Since your employee seems to be an object, try using emp.name.

Comment: the `->` is used since emp is a pointer. emp.name results in a compile error. Accessing unknown 'name' getter method.

Comment: have you declared a property for name? Also can you post the employee class definition?